# Why using PostPersist in Symfony Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I spent 3 hours trying to share on social networks some links on the `PostPersist callback`. But, the links gave me `404 error` on the social network pages. I just figured out the data that I flushed did not really exist when the PostPersist callback fired.But, in the controller after the `entity->flush()`, I used the same code, then the links work fine.

I would like to know, why exactly people use the

```
/**
* @ORM\PostPersist
*/
```

callback.

Comment: What has your story of the social networks sites to do with the question of why you would use PostPersist? Use PostPersist to sent a mail to an user after an entity has been created so it's based on an event. So you don't need to do it after every flush, within each controller which creates that entity for you.

Comment: I agree, in case it is an event occurring on every persist of the given entity consider using a [custom event subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html). They are way more flexible than any callback event.

Comment: @Kwido The social network example is to explain that the data has not yet inserted into the database during the PostPersist callback. But the data has been inserted into the database after the call to flush().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events):

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event.

But we have to take under consideration that Doctrine2 calls transaction implicitly by default. In this approach transaction ends when you use flush() on your entity manager. That's why you cannot see data in your database unless you flush entity manager. EntityManager#flush() is where transaction starts and ends. Nevertheless we have also possibility to call transaction explicitly but it also will not let you see data in the database between starting transaction, persist object and commit transaction.

In fact you cannot omit transactions in Doctrine2, so you cannot expect that your data are visible just after persist action when PostPersist event happens.

**To achieve that you have to use PostFlush event.**

Postperist in my real life experience is used for example to:

1. Create data that are dependent to created object (i.e. automatic translations, automatic dates, some specific relations updates)
2. send notifications to other events
3. send e-mails

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Take a look at examples of `onFlush` event where you can see examples of how to traverse through unit of work to get to your object. 
[onFlush examples](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush)

To work only on specific object just use:

```
if ($entity instanceof Product) {
        // do something with the YourEntityName
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, Doctrine2 says: postFlush - The postFlush event occurs at the end of a flush operation. **This event is not a lifecycle callback.**

Comment: And your examples for Postpersist is OK. Except I don't really agree sending an email before the data has been inserted into the database.

Comment: @user3502626 take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: @user3502626 postPersist is after the insert in the database, if you look at doctrine documentation:

The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event.

Comment: @YannChabot Yep. I got it long time ago. I'm a master on ORM now.